# MapInfo: How to get the population contained within 2 geographical tables

Tags: mapinfo, attribute-joins

I using 3 different tables which are also geographical objects:

- population data; points on the map representing inhabitants (1 or more)
- region data; the map is divided in regions
- coverage data; it contains several coverage areas overlapping or not

What I am searching for is: What is the percentage of people covered by a certain coverage area in a certain region?

I tried several things but nothing worked, for example with SQL select I tried:

Select Columns: Regions.name, CoverageArea.name, Sum(Population.inhabitants)

from Tables: Regions, CoverageArea, Population

where Condition: Regions.obj Contains Population.obj And CoverageArea.obj Contains Population.obj

Group by Columns: 1, 2

Order by Columns: 1, 2

into Table Named: Selection

"And I get Incorrect tables are joined. Invalid join condition in WHERE clause."

Hope I was clear enough :s

** edit **

Few tests I did. I can't understand why the thrid SQL query doesn't work...

[image: Population per coverage area]

[image: Population per region]

[image: Trying to get population per region and coverage area]

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you can join at least three tables using alfanumerical values, but I have never tried doing it using a spatial join.

But you need to make sure that your join matches the order of the tables:

```
where table1.some_column = table2.some_column
and table2.some_column = table3.some_column
```

The same properly is true if you are using a spatial join:

```
where table1.obj Intersects table2.obj
and table2.obj Intersects table3.obj
```

Comment: Well, that was it, thank you. The joining order matters. I am new to SQL commands so I was wondering is it always the case that the joining order matters? I mean also for tables (not geographical objects). For example, "where obj1.A = obj2.A and Obj3.B = Obj2.B" isn't the same as "where obj1.A = obj2.A and Obj2.B = Obj3.B"

Comment: You just proved that it's important for spatial joins, and I know it's important for alfanumerical joins. That's however only the case when using the MapInfo Pro SQL language.